# WooCommerce - Modify product's price when product is saved/updated in admin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to update the product's price when it's published/updated. One possible use case is if the price of the product entered by user is more than $100 then I want to change the price to $100.

Here's what I have tried but doesn't work:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_product_object_save', 'set_price_upper_limit' );
function set_price_upper_limit( $product ) {
    if ( $product->get_price() > 100 ) {
        $product->set_regular_price( 100 );
        $product->set_price( 100 );
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to save() the product.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_product_object_save', 'set_price_upper_limit' );
function set_price_upper_limit( $product ) {
    if ( $product->get_price() > 100 ) {
        $product->set_regular_price( 100 );
        $product->set_price( 100 );
        $product->save(); // Don't forget to save.
    }
}
```